# how to set facebook token in sharebutton codename one?

Tags: codenameone, share-button

I'm trying to share content to facebook from my Codename One application but the token is null in the network monitor tool.

[image]

Comment: I edited your question and included the image inside. You need to edit it too and include the source code that generated this for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The Share Button will work on device without the Facebook token as it will integrate with the natively installed apps on the device and share to the users facebook account. This is behavior related to the simulator and platforms that don't support native sharing intents.

You can login to Facebook for a token, you can check the section about that in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html) but this is unnecessary for real device code.